# Scaffold' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier, Widget) => Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

In my simple application which i want to use `Provider` v3 i get this error:

> The following assertion was thrown building
>   BaseWidget(dirty, state:
>   _BaseWidgetState#f3d70): type '(BuildContext, LoginViewModel, Widget) => Scaffold' is not a subtype of type
>   '(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier, Widget) => Widget'

i'm trying to implememting [this tutorial](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/flutter-provider-v3-architecture/) and i think i implemented all codes like with the tutorial.

**after 7 hour for test and check why i get error i can't find**

i get this error in this code:

```
class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseWidget<LoginViewModel>(
      model: LoginViewModel(),
      child: Text('test'),
      builder: (context, model, child) => Scaffold(
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

`BaseWidget` class:

```
class BaseWidget<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T model, Widget child) builder;
  final T model;
  final Widget child;
  final Function(T) onModelReady;
  BaseWidget({
    Key key,
    this.builder,
    this.model,
    this.child,
    this.onModelReady,
  }) : super(key: key);
  _BaseWidgetState<T> createState() => _BaseWidgetState<T>();
}
class _BaseWidgetState<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends State<BaseWidget<T>> {
  T model;
  @override
  void initState() {
    model = widget.model;
    if (widget.onModelReady != null) {
      widget.onModelReady(model);
    }
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<T>(
      builder: (context) => model,
      child: Consumer<T>(
        builder: widget.builder,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`LoginViewModel` class:

```
class LoginViewModel extends BaseModel {

}
```

`BaseModel` class:

```
class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _busy = false;
  bool get busy => _busy;

  void setBusy(bool value) {
    _busy = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: i have same issue.. did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggested

> '(BuildContext, LoginViewModel, Widget) => Scaffold' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier, Widget) => Widget'

Here all parameters is correct except one which is LoginViewModel. BuildContext is passing as BuildContext, Widget is passing as Widget & Scaffold is a Widget so it is be correct as well.

After watching this mismatch in LoginViewModel & ChangeNotifier, I visited the tutorial link you provided. There I found this

> class LoginViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {

So the issue is class **LoginViewModel** is not the direct child of **ChangeNotifier** class but of class LoginViewModel extends ChangeNotifier { & the Flutter is looking for the direct child of **ChangeNotifier**.

Do revisit the tutorial & try to create **LoginViewModel** which extends **ChangeNotifier**.
If issue still persist then let us know.

Comment: So how do you fix it?  I should be able to pass any descendant  of ChangeNotifier into it, but it doesn't work.